# WARNING: :tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls triggered tf.function retracing during Machine Learning Crash Course by Developers.google

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

I'm following "[Introduction to Machine Learning Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/first-steps-with-tensorflow/programming-exercises)" held by Google. 
Keras and Tensorflow is used in coding exercises. In one of the beginning exercises on linear regression, i have this code where a simple linear regression model using just 1 variable is created.

```
training_df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv")
training_df["median_house_value"] /= 1000
```

```
def build_model(my_learning_rate):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1, )))
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=my_learning_rate),
                 loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
    return model

def train_model(model, df, feature, label, epochs, batch_size):
    history = model.fit(x = df[feature], 
                        y = df[label], 
                        batch_size = batch_size, 
                        epochs = epochs)
    
    trained_weight = model.get_weights()[0]
    trained_bias = model.get_weights()[1]
    
    epochs = history.epoch
    hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
    rmse = hist["root_mean_squared_error"]
    
    return trained_weight, trained_bias, epochs, rmse
```

```
def plot_the_model(trained_weight, trained_bias, feature, label):
    plt.xlabel("feature")
    plt.ylabel("label")
    
    random_examples = training_df.sample(n=200)
    plt.scatter(random_examples[feature], random_examples[label])
    
    x0 = 0
    y0 = trained_bias
    x1 = random_examples[feature].max()
    y1 = trained_bias + (trained_weight * x1)
    plt.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], c="r")
    
    plt.show()

def plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse):
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel("Root MSE")
    
    plt.plot(epochs, rmse, label="Loss")
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim([rmse.min()*0.97, rmse.max()])
    plt.show()
```

We define this functions to create the model, train the model, plot the model, and plot the loss.
In order to make prediction using the model, we define this last function to make the actual prediction.
Then I choose hyperparameters and i create a synthetic feature to make the prediction.

```
def predict_house_values(n, feature, label):
    # predict house value based on a feature
    batch = training_df[feature][10000:10000+n]
    predicted_values = my_model.predict_on_batch(x=batch)
    print("feature      label          predicted")
    print("value        value          value")
    print("             in thousand    in thousand")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    for i in range(n):
        print("%5.0f %6.0f %15.0f" % (training_df[feature][10000 + i],
                                   training_df[label][10000 + i],
                                   predicted_values[i][0] ))
```

```
training_df["rooms_per_person"] = training_df["total_rooms"] / training_df["population"]

my_feature = "rooms_per_person"
my_label = "median_house_value"
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 50
batch_size = 30

my_model = build_model(learning_rate)
weight, bias, epochs, rmse = train_model(my_model, training_df,
                                         my_feature, my_label,
                                         epochs, batch_size)

plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse)
plot_the_model(weight, bias, my_feature, my_label)
predict_house_values(15, my_feature, my_label)
```

I Run this last block of code to predict the `median_house_value` using the `room_per_person` feature. 
Everything works fine, but a warning appears.

> WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

I think that the issue might be in `for` loop inside the `predict_house_values` function, but I am not sure.
How can I improve the code to avoid getting this warning? And can tracing/retracing of `tf.function` cause more serious issues in more complex problems?

Comment: none of those are tf.functions, so something aint right...

Comment: Does this appear during training, or during prediction?

Comment: It appeared when I ran the last block of code, i think during prediction. But the last time I ran the code the warning didn't appear...